# PHP login authentication not working

Tags: php, html, authentication, php-7

I have two .php files. All html and php, no SQL and will not be needing/using it. One is the login page, the other is the destination. When I put in the log in details I have set, I can't get to the destination. As you can see, `session_start();` is clearly at the top. I even put it right on the same line as the opening php tag and no difference was made. Here's the code for both pages:

Login:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username="testu";
$password="testp";
$_SESSION['logged_in']=false;   

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
    header("Location: dest.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    if ($_POST['user'] == $username && $_POST['pass'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header("Location: dest.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>A title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="dest.php" method="post" style="font-    family:calibri;position:absolute;top:40%;left:35%;">
        Username: <input type="text" name="user"/><br><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass"     style="position:relative;left:5px;"/><br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="position:relative;left:115px;"/>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Destination:

```
(php tag here)
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] == false) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>A title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="login.php">Log out</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I noticed that when I commented out the php code on the destination file, I could access the dest.php. Issue is, I could access is with any login details, or none at all. It's either nothing works, or anything works. How can I get the details I have set to work? I feel the issue is in the login page script. Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help me resolve this.

Note: I had to repost this because my last question was marked as a duplicate of something completely irrelevant to my issue, thank you.

Comment: Change `<form action="dest.php"` to `<form action="login.php"` OR put your login script in `dest.php`. Right now you are doing a loop - your form data is sent to `dest.php`, and since you are not logged in, it sends you back to `login.php`, but since it does not post the form that you sent to `dest.php`, it never checks your login, so you have to try logging in again.

Comment: @Sean Thank you, someone actually paid attention to my code and got this right. It makes perfect sense as well. Please post this as an answer so I can give more legitimate credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Sean beat me to it, nice job :-)**

If you remove the `action="dest.php"` it should work. Right now you are sending the form to a page that does not check the values of the username and password, thus the session variable is not set.

```
<form method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"/>
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
action="dest.php"
```

You must make sure code below is in the file `dest.php`, and delete it from `login.php`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username="testu";
$password="testp";
$_SESSION['logged_in']=false;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
    header("Location: dest.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    if ($_POST['user'] == $username && $_POST['pass'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header("Location: dest.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```